# Trigger email for selected and not selected candidates when item modified using flow

Tags: sharepoint-online

List schema

As per the list schema when item SRroles is modified as Main ,Backup for specific vacancy ID then we may need to trigger email in foreach in the same logic and email should get triggered to SRroles Main and SRroles null for each specific vacancyID from the list.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question? When flow should trigger? Exactly for each VacancyID and SRroles column values?

Comment: 1.When HR(one of them) will select two candidates for each position: One main and one backup. When the candidates are selected:
1.1.1.A notification will be sent to the selected main candidate including a meeting invitation for the meeting. 
1.1.2.A notification will be sent to Human Resources team.
1.1.3.A notification will be sent to those volunteers that were not selected.

Comment: You cannot user trigger condition based on column values from two separate list items.

Comment: You can use scheduled flow ("Recurrence" trigger) which will run daily and read the vacancy IDs and if list has two entries (Main & Backup) for the vacancy ID, then send email notification. After sending email notification for any vacancy - you can update list item row with one hidden flag column which will indicate that email is already sent for the vacancy ID so that it will avoid sending emails next day for same vacancy ID.

Comment: We have only one list and its shortlisted list we need to filter this condition concerned to shortlisted list

Comment: HR will manage to select candidates from shortlisted list and its done manually so we have to check the above criteria in shortlisted list only

Comment: Ok can you please help me with flow steps it would be helpful .Thanks so much for all your great inputs

Comment: Also we need to check if the specific vacancyid got no roles then we need to send email for vacnacies ID not selected.

Comment: We need email when roles is Backup as they are selected candidate for that vacancyid and if there is no role for the same vacancyID so on for each vacancy id etc then that candidate is not selected

Comment: ALso i forgot if volunteer column should be yes and role is empty then only not selected criteria

Comment: can you please help me with flow steps and it would be very helpful?Thanks for all your great inputs

Comment: Kindly help with sample flow and I need steps for checking who are not selected and selected as per above scenario. If selected then candidates should have status role is Main and interested column is Yes and to see if candidate is notselected then status roles is empty and interested column is Yes so we need to trigger email .Please help

Comment: Your question is very vague. Requirements/conditions are also very complex to understand and answer. The question needs to be more focused. Try to break multiple questions/requirements in separate questions/posts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs